# Passing optional array from PHP to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem if this optional array is empty:

```
<script>
    var parsedArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>');
    console.log(parsedArray );
</script>
```

All is fine if array is NOT empty, but the problem comes if there are no values in array;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Console.log just spits `Array` out if array is empty.

I want to learn how is this done properly. How to pass an empty array to jQuery so I can run `myArray.length` function on it for example and so that it returns 0 if it is empty.

Comment: How does the **generated** input look like?

Comment: Normally if `$myArray` is an empty `array()` json_encode should return `[]` so I'm not sure where the syntax error is coming from. What does the response from `json_encode($myArray);` look like if empty or rather what is `$myArray` looking like?

Comment: It just gives a string `Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to do the if statement i figured it out and my problem was that I did the json_encode($myArray) in PHP code and then JSON.parse in javascript

it works like this without problems:

in PHP just declare the array

```
$myArray = [];
```

and in php file under script spit it out like this:

```
var myArray = <?= json_encode($myArray) ?>;
```

And now even if array is empty it will spit out `[]`;

Answer (score 2):

You can use tenary operators when echoing out your `$myArray`. If it is empty, you can simply pass `null` to `JSON.parse` instead, i.e.:

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo !empty($myArray) ? json_encode($myArray) : "null"; ?>');
console.log(parsedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the above answer, I would also add the `'`s to the PHP:

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo !empty($myArray) ? "'" . json_encode($myArray) . "'" : "null"; ?>);
console.log(parsedArray);
```

Because we wouldn't use `null` as `'null'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `$myArray` when echoing it out and do something if it is empty. What to do depends on how you will be using `parsedArray` afterwords. You can pass an empty array `[]`:

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo !empty($myArray)? json_encode($myArray) : "[]"; ?>');
console.log(parsedArray);
```